# How do I call this function on blur(), using JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this function, see below:

```
function checkStartPrice (){
    if ($('#StartingPrice')[0].value.length == 0){
        alert("The 'Starting Price' cannot be left empty!");
        return false;
     } else {
        var BuyItNowPrice = parseFloat($('#BuyItNowPrice').val());
        var StartingPrice = parseFloat($('#StartingPrice').val());
        var Reserve = parseFloat($('#Reserve').val());
        if((BuyItNowPrice <= StartingPrice) && (StartingPrice > 0)){
            alert("The 'Buy It Now' price must be higher...");
            return false;
        }
        if((Reserve <= StartingPrice) && (StartingPrice > 0)){
            alert("Your 'Reserve Price' must be higher...");
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Question: How do I call it on blur? I tried this code below but it doesn't seem to work:

```
$('#StartingPrice').blur(function(){
    checkStartPrice();
});
```

Comment: It will work, even `$('#StartingPrice').blur(checkStartPrice)` will do, if you correctly call it in the `document.ready` callback. The DOM has to be loaded for this to work. See http://api.jquery.com/ready/

Comment: What the type of the The #StartingPrice?  It`s need to be of type that support blur event

Comment: @Felix-Kling The error was somewhere else in my JS file...which cause the script not to work. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the correct way to call it.
The only reason it may fail is that the #StartingPrice element does not exist at the time of the .blur() call.

If it is present in the page, use this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#StartingPrice').blur(checkStartPrice)
})
```

If it is dynamically added via AJAX, use this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#StartingPrice').live('blur',checkStartPrice)
})
```

Note that the second solution requires at least jQuery 1.4.1